# How to display this little white x-circle in a UITextField, so users can delete the text?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

Some apps have this nice little white circle with an gray x in there UITextField. How can I add this to an UITextField and delete the text when it is tapped?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To add a button like this, you can use the **clearButtonMode** property of an UITextField.
The code will be like this:

```
// Show cancel button never
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;  

// Show cancel button only when you're editing text in textField
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;  

// Show the cancel button only when you aren't editing the text
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing;

// Show always the cancel button
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [clearButtonMode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/clearButtonMode) property.